# Is this sentence correct「小説は読みます」?

Tags: particle-は

Is this sentence correct?

> 小説は読みます

I've learned that は is a topic marker not an object marker. In this case it's acting as an object marker to 小説 since 読む is transitive a verb.

Now according to the blog I got this from ([here](https://selftaughtjapanese.com/2015/02/26/japanese-particle-combination-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF-de-wa-and-%E3%81%98%E3%82%83-ja/)) it's supposed to imply that the speaker reads novels but doesn't read other things such as short stories.

> One of the functions of は is to imply something applies for the word before the は, but there may be other cases that do not apply.

> 小説は読みます

> This implies that the speaker reads novels, but there is probably something he or she doesn’t read (maybe short stories?).

Comment: Subject and topic are separate concepts. Particles が, を, に, で and some others belong to case particles ([格助詞](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/格助詞)). When combining topic particle は with most case particles, は is placed after case particle (e.g. には, では), but は **replaces** が and を particles (however there is also archaic [をば](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/をば) combination, formed from を + は, with voicing of は (this particle was pronounced /pa/ until supposedly 10th century)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sentence, 小説 *is* the object of 読む, but that doesn't mean it's not the topic of the sentence. Just like a word can be a subject and a topic at the same time, a word can be a topic and an object at the same time. In other words, "topic" is a concept that is independent of "case".

- 私は走ります。
  I run.
  (私 is the subject of 走る **and** the topic of the sentence)
- 小説は読みます。
  As for novels, (I) read (them).
  (小説 is the object of 読む **and** the topic of the sentence)

For details, please read [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17574/5010) and [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/98017/5010).

See also [What is a topic prominent language?](https://eastasiastudent.net/study/topic-prominent/)

> The topic of a sentence is whatever the sentence is about. It’s not a grammatical role like the subject, but a more pragmatic aspect of the sentence. The topic is the most important piece of information - it’s what the sentence is built around.